# Apache 2.4 reverse proxy setup cannot impose basic authentication

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I have apache2.4 set up and when visiting any apache served web sites basic authentication works great.

Now I have one more webserver running from an other service at port 8000 and I wanted to setup apache as a reverse proxy hoping that it can also impose and handle basic authentication there as well...but instead for asking for user and password it just serves the website unprotected.

my setup is:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.101:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.101:8000/
<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authorization"
AuthUserFile /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Update:
solution found by marked answer:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.101:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.101:8000/
    
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization"
    AuthUserFile /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure that apache is configured to listen to that port and also if the proxied server is local it is not running at the same port as listened one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Apache doesn't 'link' `Proxypass / http://example.com` and `<Location />` - even though they both try to work with `/`. This means that Proxypass is handling requests for '/' first, and the `Location` section is never being used.

You need to move the Proxy config inside the `Location`, dropping the path, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.101:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.101:8000/
    
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorization"
    AuthUserFile /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution, that was the correct answer, misconfiguration from 2 days trying various things made it look like it doesn't work, but I figured my mistakes and now it works great! thanks again!